# How to get previous URL on session expire in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get **previous url** on empty session for example if a user open a webpage directly by typing url e.g. xyz.com/dashboard/ then because he was not logged in and session was empty so he will be redirected to xyz.com/login/ where he will enter his credentials and will automatically redirected to xyz.com/dashboard/

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask questions. It's unlikely that you will get a good answer for this question.

Comment: I've just reset your reputation, please take time to improve your question (mainly lacking of info showing your effort).

Answer (score 1):

Redirect user to `xyz.com/login?next=<the url user accessed>` and then after successful login redirect the user to the URL specified in the `next` query string value.

Comment: I normally used this approach but we can also do the same using cookies and sessions I think.

Comment: @MAdeelKhalid Yes u can, basically the idea is to somehow send the previous URL as part of the request because of the stateless nature of HTTP

Comment: Agree but what if the session of 2 different people/users expires at the same time and both were on the different pages, how the query string will be unique for both of them?

Answer (score -1):

To complement @Ankur answer, i am including MVC and Angular JS code to achieve the required behavior.

AccountController.cs

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("login")]
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
                return RedirectToAction("Home", "Dashboard");

            return View(new AccountLoginModel() { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Login()
        {

            if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
                return RedirectToAction("Home", "Dashboard");

            return View(new AccountLoginModel() { ReturnUrl = string.Empty });
        }
```

Login.chtml

```
<div data-ng-controller="AccountLoginViewModel" ng-init="returnUrl = '@Model.ReturnUrl'" class="centered">

... HTML code here

<button type="button" class="btn" ng-click="login()">Login</button>

</div>
```

AccountLoginViewModel.js

```
$scope.login = function () {
            viewModelHelper.apiPost('api/account/login', $scope.accountModel,
                function (result) {

                    if ($scope.returnUrl != '' && $scope.returnUrl.length > 1) {
                        window.location.href = rootPath + $scope.returnUrl.substring(1);
                    }
                    else {
                        window.location.href = rootPath + "dashboard/home";
                    }
                });
        }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try

```
[Authorize]
```

before the every actions in controller like

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Dashboard()
{
}
```

add below code in Web.Config Configuration

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms defaultUrl="/Home/Profile" loginUrl="/Home/Index" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="2880"></forms>
</authentication>
```